# TextMeshPro not properly displaying "\n" new lines

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my game, I am grabbing a random string from a text file and Changing a GameObjects TextMeshPro.Text to this line.

```
[SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI endOfContentText;
[SerializeField] private TextAsset       messageTextFile;

private void OnEnable() {
    TextChangerOuter(ParseTextAsset());
}

private void ParseTextAsset() {
    var arrayString  = messageTextFile.text.Split('\n');
    foreach (var line in arrayString) {
        listOfWords.Add(line);
    }
}

private void TextChangerOuter(string text) {
        var rand      = new Random();
        var randomKey = listOfWords.ElementAt(rand.Next(0, listOfWords.Count));
        listOfWords.Remove(randomKey);
        endOfContentText.text = randomKey;
}
```

The problem I am experiencing is that some line in this file contains "\n" new lines as part of the joke. At first, I was worried that the `ParseTextAsset()` method would split this line up creating many blank lines but that did not happen. What I did not expect was for TextMeshPro to not parce the following line correctly.

[image]

Oddly if I go into the inspector and change the text manually, or turn the TextMeshPro component off and back on manually the text reformats as expected.

[image]

In the past I have used `Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases();` to fix some aspects of my UI, but this time its not working this time. I even wrote a Coroutine to disable and re-enable this component after it generates the text but that did not work.

```
private IEnumerator SetShowNewMessageAfterFrame() {
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    endOfContentText.enabled = false;
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    endOfContentText.enabled = true;
    Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases();
}
```

EDIT:

As per Berk Askin's answer Project Settings / TextMeshPro / Settings > [Parse Escape Sequence] was already set and produced the above results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `<br>` tag to force a line break in text.

Example:

```
Add line breaks wherever you want

Add line breaks <br>wherever <br>you <br>want
```

[image]

https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@3.2/manual/RichTextLineBreak.html

Comment: Thank you, I will add this to my kanban board to try out later. It has been a while sense I have opened that project and still have yet to get this to work.

Comment: Thanks again, I finally got back to my project and tested this. <br> works as a line break for TextMesh Pro.

Answer (score 2):

TMpro components has option to show/hide escape sequences, you just need to turn it on at
Project Settings / TextMeshPro / Settings and find [Parse Escape Sequence] option and open it.

Comment: Hmm looks like that setting was already checked.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this same issue when using the Unity Localisation system instead of a TextAsset as source, but the underlying issue might be the same:

According to the TMP developer Stephan_B:

> Is the text coming from some external source / file (xml, json, etc.)? If that is the case, you have to be mindful that these control characters are likely being escaped as they are not allowed in those format. So the "\n" becomes "\\n" which results in C# interpreting this as a string literal which results in "\" + "n" instead of linefeed or char(10).
> ( https://forum.unity.com/posts/3588597 )

As suggested in that thread, doing a string replace("\\n", "\n") immediately after the import solved those issues for me.